# GVIM + CSCOPE + CTAGS over Windows

Tags: windows, vim, mingw, ctags, cscope

I've setup my windows machine to work with gvim + cscope + ctags as I used to do with my older Linux environment.

Cscope is working but only partially, some of the commands does not work:

```
:cs find e foo /find a pattern/
:cs find t foo /find a text/
:cs find i foo /find files including this file/
```

The other ones seems to work fine.
This is the generation tags script that I'm running over a minGW:

```
rm -f tags 
rm -f cscope.*
find . -type f -name *.c  ! -path "./bin/*" -o -name *.h   ! -  path "./bin/*"  -o -name SCons*   ! -path "./bin/*" >cscope.files
cscope -icscope.files -b -q -k
/c/Users/M0081495/Downloads/ctags58/ctags58/ctags.exe -R -L cscope.files
```

Comment: [SOLVED] Finally I solved the issue installing a native windows cscope.exe executable. So far I was using a cygwin built-in cscope application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] Finally I solved the issue installing a native windows cscope.exe executable. So far I was using a cygwin built-in cscope application.